# ReactJS/Redux: Rerender Parent and Child With Same Selector?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following:

Parent render():

```js
render() {
    const {flag} = this.props;
    <ToRefresh key={flag}/>
    <Child/>
}
```

Child render:

```js
render() {
   const {flag} = this.props;
   console.log("FLAG IN CHILD: " + flag); //flag is present from Redux store
   <ToRefresh key={flag}/>
}
```

Both Parent and Child should have their ToRefresh components refreshed based on the `flag` key, which comes from a Redux store (initialized by an action, has a selector etc).

The `ToRefresh` in the Parent refreshes correctly, but the `ToRefresh` in the Child does not refresh.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? From my understanding, this is the right way of refreshing components when using redux.

Comment: Child component looks like doesnot receive the flag props

Comment: It receives it, I checked with console.log(...) :(

Comment: where? <Child flag={flag} />?

Comment: Both Parent and Child have their props initialized in Parent.connect.js and Child.connect.js from the Redux store, using a selector.

Comment: Please make a clear question. you wrote const { flag } = this.props. add some code or share the whole code!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have so much experience with React. But I'm sure flag reaches Child correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234653/discussion-between-topw3-and-amihaiemil).

Comment: try not to use key. It's a special keyword. Just use <Tofresh prop1={flag} />